# php oop mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, oop, foreach

I received some help moments ago, but was never able to find out why this query is not working? How might I modify this to make it work?

```
class Posts {

  public static function multipleQuery() {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3")
              , __CLASS__);

      while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $return[] = $object;
      }
      return $return;
  }
}


$array = Posts::multipleQuery();
foreach($array AS $row) {
   echo $row->title;
}
```

Unfortunately I am not getting anything back. The query works, I have tested that out.

Comment: Try `var_dump($array)`. Also `, __CLASS__)` is misplaced. Please be more specific on what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: What happens, what doesn't work? EIther way, this looks wrong `), __CLASS__);`

Comment: Are you missing the database connection or is it just not part of this snippet?

Comment: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);` set at the top of your script will ensure that errors are displayed and should help you to debug this.

Comment: Looking at the code, you have invalid syntax on line 3. Remove `, __CLASS__)`.

Comment: I have the database connection. that's all sound and good. whats wrong with the __CLASS__  ?

Comment: Beautiful. Yah that was it. I modified previous code and thats why it was there. Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

The second argument on mysql_query should be a mysql connection handle. Passing your classe's name is not such a handle, so you're trying to execute the query on a database connection which doesn't exist. As well, you have no error checking, which would've shown this problem:

```
public static function multipleQuery(){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3") 
              or die(mysql_error());

    while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $return[] = $object;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have error reporting turned off, and are thus not seeing the parse error that should result from this line:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 3"), __CLASS__);
```

I see two parentheses closed but only one opened.

Also you shouldn't throw the class name in there anyway. If anything, you should put in the object for the database connection, not the name of the class.